# Rotate animation on x-axis

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-animation

I want to rotate my image on x-axis, I tried many alternatives, also tried `Rotate3dAnimation` and it always rotate on Y axis. I want to do my image as:

[image: question image 1]

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `android.graphics.Camera.rotateX(degrees);`

Answer (score 1):

Old question but no solid answer yet. So :

In case your Image is a view you can use [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) (Minimal implementation) like this :

```
yourImage.animate().rotateX(360);
```

You can chain together all the methods that you need and customize your animation f.e. :

```
yourImage.animate()
    .rotateX(360)
    .setDuration(1000)
    .setStartDelay(500)
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator);
```

Check all available methods in the docs.
[ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) is available since API 12.